# Python - No module named but the module exist it

Tags: python, module, directory

I have the next directory structure:

```
|-Server/
|-------OrderBook/
|       |--------message.py
|       |--------orderBookObject.py
|-------Rabbit/
|       |--------emisor.py
|       |--------receptor.py
|-------server.py
|-------processMessage.py
```

In server.py I have **"from processMessage import A"**

In processMessage.py I have **"from OrderBook.orderBookObject import B"**

and in orderBookObject.py I have **"from Rabbit.emisor import C"**

but I have the next error **"ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Rabbit"**

Why is this happening?

How can I fix it?

**Edit:**
If I move Rabbit folder inside OrderBook folder, I have the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

create a file named `__init__.py` inside directory OrderBook and Rabbit

this will create package, and then you can import

https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#packages

so your directory structure will be looked like :

```
|-Server/
|-------OrderBook/
|       |--------__init__.py
|       |--------message.py
|       |--------orderBookObject.py
|-------Rabbit/
|       |--------__init__.py
|       |--------emisor.py
|       |--------receptor.py
|-------server.py
|-------processMessage.py
```